# MVC Entity Framework - Dispose Instances of DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, code-first

There has been other similar posts on here which I have read, but still not clear. Rather than necro something old and hope for a response, I hope nobody minds re-awakening a subject matter.

The question is when to dispose the DbContext.
Here is an example of a Controller on my MVC application

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
          using (var db = new TheCurve.Models.TheCurveDb())
           {
              var result = db.GetTopArticles().ToList();
              return View(result);
           }

        }
```

In this example, the Razor view throws an exception as the DbContext has been disposed due to the Using Block.

If I do not dispose the DbContext the Razor view throws the error 'there is already an open datareader associated with this command ' when it tries to access properties on the Model such as this piece of code.

```
var type = Model.ArticleType.Type;
    switch (type)
    {
        case "Example":
            defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/example.png";
            break;

        case "Download":
            defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/download.png";
            break;

        case "Link":
            defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/link.png";
            break;

        case "Article":
            defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/article.png";
            break;

    }
```

I know the DbContext closes the connection after retrieving the data, but does this mean it won't need disposed?

Many Thanks

-Edit

Partial View showing an article overview.

```
    @model TheCurve.Models.Article


@{
    //Shorten description for Article overview
    var strDescription = Model.Description.Length > 250 ? Model.Description.Substring(0, 250) + "..." : Model.Description + "...";

    //Decide which image to show on overview.
    string defaultTitleImage = null;
    if (Model.TitleImage == null)
    {
        var type = Model.ArticleType.Type;
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Example":
                defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/example.png";
                break;

            case "Download":
                defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/download.png";
                break;

            case "Link":
                defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/link.png";
                break;

            case "Article":
                defaultTitleImage = "Content/themes/base/images/article.png";
                break;

        }

    }
    else
    {
        defaultTitleImage = Model.TitleImage;
    }

}


<article class="clear-fix">

<div class="float-left">
    <img src="@defaultTitleImage" alt="The Curve - Article Type"/>
</div>
<div class="float-left articleoverview">
    @Html.ActionLink(Model.Title.TrimStart(), "Details","Code", new {articleId = Model.Id}, null)
    <p>@strDescription</p>
    <p><i>By @Model.Author On @Model.DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</i></p>

</div>
</article>
```

This is the Razor view which uses the above partial.

```
@model IEnumerable<TheCurve.Models.Article>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Code Samples & Technology Blog";
}
    <section>
        <h3>Currently Viewing Most Recent Entries</h3>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_ArticleOverview", item)
        }
    </section>
```

Comment: It looks like you need to include the navigation property in the original query to allow for it to be referenced via the Razor script. Can you post your models to allow for better information please?

Comment: You should override `Dispose` method in controller and there dispose context.

Comment: One thing which makes a difference and I forgot to add. The Open Data reader error is coming up in a partial view. I will add the partial view and view using it above.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question but I think you are having an `select n+1` as indicated by the use of `Type` in `ArticleType`. And because of that when you access `Type` your dbcontext queries your database again - and hence the additional datareader. 

When you did a ToList your dbcontext gets the record out of the database and into the memory. But when you access _grand-child records_ and you did not _lazy load_ them it can cause select n+1.

Comment: Do your models have properties that are marked `virtual`? If so, those properties use lazy loading; if you dispose the context and then try to access the property later you may run into trouble - I'm not sure how Entity Framework would handle that.

Comment: So would it have been better to to JOIN in the LINQ and retrieve a strongly typed object with the Type, rather than having to pull back a grand-child? Does that not defeat what the EF is doing though? Or do you mean don't call to List which I actually added in an attempt to close the connection and not get the datareader error.

Comment: I do actually have 1 property calling virtual. Assigning the Foreign Key didn't work without it and the type was coming back NULL

Comment: The better way to do that is to shape the result of your query into a "real model" (what we refer to as Model in asp.net MVC). I don't think you would need all the columns from your table(s) into your view. So just select those you need and shape them into a flat model.

Comment: von - That would be a great idea for the partial view, but when I come to write a view for the full article I will need all columns. Would you think the same goes and create a flat model? Or is this issue only an issue because of the partial view? In the Controller, if everything is correct, should Using be used on the DbContext? Cheers

Comment: If you need all columns then it's still a good practice to have a disconnected model, especially if you will not update the record(s) you just pulled. And also that's not a good way of updating anyway. If you have a disconnected model - what I will refer to as `everything is correct` - then yes you should definitely use `using` so the DbContext is disposed for you automatically.

Comment: I have changed my DbContext Method for returning the overview data to a flat model, meaning I can no longer have a strongly typed view to the Article Model? As it won't be articles passed over to the view anymore, just anonymous types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was that the DbContext should always be in the Using Block. To prevent the error about the DbContext being disposed when accessing the object I needed to use .ToList or .ToArray to materialize the IEnumerable.

The other part of the solution was actually assisted by von by recommending using a flat model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to a SQL server with this (I presume so), then add MultipleActiveResultsets=true in your conenction string. This allows for more than one open datareader connection to a SQL server.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) for more.